# Does weighting the Likelihood Ratios by a prior give the Likelihood ratios any Bayesian property?

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, likelihood-ratio

I have a question regarding Bayesian Hypothesis testing using "Bayes Factors".

Does weighting the *Likelihood Ratios* by a *prior* give the Likelihood ratios **any property** (e.g., removing conditionality on Hypotheses, changing p(Data | Hypothesis) =to=> p(Hypothesis | Data)  etc.) that Likelihood ratios did not have before weighting?

If not, what does multiplying likelihood ratios by a prior do to Likelihood ratios?

**Here is R code to compute a Bayes Factor for a binomial experiment:**

```
 h = 35                        ## Number of `h`eads
 n = 100                       ## All Trials
p0 = .5                        ## probability of each head
 x = seq(0, 1, len = 1e5)
prior = dbeta(x, 1, 1) 

 Like.ratios = dbinom(h, n, x) / dbinom(h, n, p0)
W.Like.ratios = Like.ratios * prior       ## `W` stands for `W`eighted 
         BF10 = mean(W.Like.ratios)  ## A Bayes Factor(H1/H0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bayes factor is not a likelihood ratio and not even a weighted likelihood ratio except in the most unrealistic case of comparing two fixed values of the full parameter. In general, the Bayes factor is defined by integrating out or averaging the parameter, under each hypothesis, and using the ratio of the integrated likelihoods as a decision tool:
$$\mathfrak{B}_{12}(x)=\dfrac{\int_{\Theta_1} f(x|\theta_1) \pi_1(\theta_1)\text{d}\theta_1}{\int_{\Theta_2} f(x|\theta_2) \pi_1(\theta_2)\text{d}\theta_2}$$The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor) on this notion is reasonably helpful as an introduction on the topic, before moving to Bayesian textbooks which almost invariably deal with the topic.

Comment: Dear Xi'an, thanks. Is n't my `BF10` from above about the same as the solution below using integration:                                                                                     `H1 = integrate(function(p) dbeta(p, 1, 1)*dbinom(h, n, p), 0, 1)[[1]];
 H0 = dbinom(h, n, p0);
 BF10 = H1 / H0`

Comment: Yes using integration in this R code reproduces the exact integration written in my answer. I am however unsure how this answers the general question.

Comment: Xi'an, In my original question I intentionally didn't use integration. Because I wanted to show that we can see that Bayes Factors could be seen as `"a weighted averaged likelihood ratio"`,  I felt like you said BFs are "not even a weighted likelihood ratio". Apparently, from the perspective in my original question, may be BFs are `"a weighted averaged likelihood ratio"`?